# Create variables dynamically inside 'for' loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, coding-style

I'm new to python and trying to take some coding challenges to improve my skills. I've to take input in following ways:

```
 2
 3 1
 4 3
```

First, I get number of test cases.(2 here) Then based on that, I've to get given number of test cases that are each 2 integers. 1st is the range and second is the number to be searched in the range.

What's the correct, pythonic way of getting the input. I was thinking like this but it's obviously `incorrect`

```
num_testcases = int(raw_input())
for i in num_testcases:
    range_limit = int(raw_input())
    num_to_find = int(raw_input())
```

Comment: Downvote? Any reason? Like I said I'm beginner :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input()` is going to be read one line at a time from STDIN, so inside the loop you need to use `str.split()` to get the value of `range_limit` and `num_to_find`. Secondly you cannot iterate over an integer(`num_testcases`), so you need to use `xrange()`(Python 2) or `range()`(Python 3) there:

```
num_testcases = int(raw_input())
for i in xrange(num_testcases): #considering we are using Python 2
    range_limit, num_to_find = map(int, raw_input().split())
    #do something with the first input here
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> line = '3 1'
>>> line.split()
['3', '1']
>>> map(int, line.split())
[3, 1]
```

Note that in Python 3 you'll have to use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` and `range()` instead of  `xrange()`. `range()` will work in both Python 2 and 3, but it returns a list in Python 2, so it is recommended to use `xrange()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for i in range(num_testcases):` instead of `for i in num_testcases`. Have a look at [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#range) (or [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) in Python 2). `range(a)` produces an iterable from `0` to `a - 1`, so your code gets called the desired number of times.

---

Also, `input` and `raw_input` take input on encountering a newline, meaning that in `range_limit = int(raw_input())`, `raw_input` returns `"3 1"`, which you can't just convert to `int`. Instead, you want to *split* the string using `string.split` and then convert the individual items:

```
num_testcases = int(raw_input())
for i in range(num_testcases):
    range_limit, num_to_find = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
```

Comment: `range` produces actually a list in python 2. Use `xrange` here.

Comment: Very correct (I was not sure which version OP is on, because he tagged it both 2.7 and 3.x)

Comment: What about the inputs that I need? Based on num_testcases I need to dynamically `num_testcases*2` inputs

Comment: @Maxsteel Added that now - @Daniel Just noticed `raw_input` instead of `input` (d'oh)

Comment: Now both the answers are almost same and both works. Wasn't sure which one to accept. +1 to you. Thanks a lot for help.